Makefile: No such file or directory on an existing file, env variables not loading
I have a Makefile slightly modified to help explain the case better:
include $(wildcard .env)

DB_URL=postgres://$(POSTGRES_USER):$(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)@$(POSTGRES_HOST):$(POSTGRES_PORT)/$(POSTGRES_DB)?sslmode=disable&pool_max_conns=10

test:
    @echo $(DB_URL)
    @cat .env
    @-include .env
    @echo "Running tests"
    @DB=$(DB_URL) go test ./... -v -coverprofile=coverage.out

The first line shows the right DB URL being created, so it's importing the .env file as expected. The second line works too. The third line shows following error:
make: include: No such file or directory
make: [test] Error 1 (ignored)

Now, while I can see my DB URL being present, I don't understand why I cannot see anything in DB. go test showed DB being an empty string. If I export the hardcoded DB url, everything is working as expected.
It would be great if someone could help me understand why this is happening. I'm using MacOS Sonoma. I've been using the same Makefile for a couple weeks, and never changed .env or Makefile, but this stopped working a couple hours back.

First rule of debugging makefiles, never ever add @ to the beginning of your recipe lines.  It's like running a compiler and sending the output to /dev/null.

Second, there's no way this makefile used to work before.  The line include .env is a makefile statement.  But you have indented it and made it part of the recipe, which means it will be passed to the shell for it to execute.  There's no include command in the shell, or, most likely, in any bin directory on your PATH.

You're right. The third line was a debug statement. I wanted to see what was going wrong. I apologise for not mentioning it earlier.
Also, what you said makes sense. I didn't realise my mistake there. Thank you for pointing out!

I guess since you ignore the error it could have "worked", but it was definitely always printing the error about include: No such file or directory.

Good point. I'll keep this in my mind. Thank you!

Being outside a recipe, this ...
include $(wildcard .env)

... is a directive to make.
Being inside a recipe, this ...
    @-include .env

is a shell command, modulo the @- that suppresses printing the command and does not terminate the recipe on errors.  But include is not a shell built-in, and, unsurprisingly, there is no such command in the executable search path, hence:

make: include: No such file or directory


You continue ...

Now, while I can see my DB URL being present, I don't understand why I cannot see anything in DB. go test showed DB being an empty string.

You need to be careful about quoting.  make expands $(DB_URL) to a string that ends with sslmode=disable&pool_max_conns=10.  The & is significant to the shell as a command separator (that causes the preceding command to be run as a background job).  So yes, go test will not see a value for DB in its environment, or at least not because the recipe sets one.  The only addition it will see to its environment is pool_max_conns=10, which you didn't even mean for it to get.
There could be other, similar issues if the URL contained other characters significant to the shell, such as ; or $, among others.  As long as the URL does not contain any ' characters, you should be able to do this:
    DB='$(DB_URL)' go test ./... -v -coverprofile=coverage.out

Side note: never suppress command echo in your recipes until you are sure they are working correctly.  And maybe not even then.

Oh thank you! This clarifies my doubts. I had just made some changes to my Postgres URL, and added &pool_max_conns=10 at the end, and missed enclosing the variable in quotes.
A couple of things to clarify:

The include directive was never in the recipe. I only added it to see what went wrong. Your and @MadScientist's comments made me realise my error. It was include file that wasn't found, not `.env.
Given these environment variables contain secrets, I don't think it's a good idea to remove suppress. It was by choice given the secrets could potentially leak through logs.

